# CodeIgniter Active Record - Get number of returned rows and get the sum

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter and Active Record in particular

How can I Get number of returned rows and get the SUM of two returned tables row counts.

I already have function to get row count like this

**controller**

```
 function newsletter (){    
        $data = array();
        $data['subscriber_count'] =$this->mod_contactus->count_subscriber();
        $data['user_count'] =$this->mod_contactus->count_reg_users();
        $this->load->view('admin/admin_newsletter',$data);
    }
```

**model**

```
 public function count_subscriber() {
       return $this->db->get("tbl_subscribers")->num_rows();
    }   


    public function count_reg_users() {
        return $this->db->get("tbl_customer_registration")->num_rows();
    }
```

Comment: have you tried $this->db->count_all_results(); or $this->db->count_all(); ? Reference: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: What's wrong with using simple addition to get the sum? You already have the row counts.

Comment: @WesleyMurch yes you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a big deal. You can do something like this. Assist PHP `array_sum` .This is [php manual to array sum](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) You already have the row counts

in your controller

```
function newsletter (){    
    $data = array();
    $data['subscriber_count'] =$this->mod_contactus->count_subscriber();
    $data['user_count'] =$this->mod_contactus->count_reg_users();
    $data['count_both'] =  array_sum($data);
    $this->load->view('admin/admin_newsletter',$data);    
}
```

in your view  `echo $count_both ;`

Answer (score 1):

If that's really your only goal, just execute one query:

```
$query = $this->db->query("
    select 
    ( select count(*) from table_1 ) +
    ( select count(*) from table_2 ) 
    as total_num_row
    from table_1
");

# $query->num_rows()
```

Comment: That's what we call ActiveRecord ;)

Comment: You should update your previous answer instead of deleting and then posting new answer